# Toggle Switch lable

Tags: css, toggle

Im used **`Toggle Switch`** i need to put switch `open` and `close`  label  behind the switch , look `image 01` and `image 02` you can understand my issue,
this is  a two type `Open` and `closed` `Switch Open` after displayed `open`  `Switch Closed` after displayed `Closed`, please look  the working snippet 
how can i fix it, 
please help me to fix this

Thanks

**Image 01**- current view

[image]

**Image 02** - i need like this

[image]

```css
 .onoffswitch1 {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch1-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 30px;
}

.onoffswitch1-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch1-inner:before, .onoffswitch1-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
}

.onoffswitch1-inner:before {
    content: "YES";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #2FCCFF; color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

.onoffswitch1-inner:after {
    content: "NO";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
}

.onoffswitch1-switch {
    display: block; width: 30px; margin: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 56px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px white inset;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch1-label .onoffswitch1-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch1-label .onoffswitch1-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="onoffswitch1">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch1" class="onoffswitch1-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch1" checked>
                  <label class="onoffswitch1-label" for="myonoffswitch1">
                    <span class="onoffswitch1-inner"></span>
                    <span class="onoffswitch1-switch"></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @vel sir i updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this is what you need. You may have to tweak the colors and the position of the text.

```css
.onoffswitch1 {
  width: 90px;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch1-label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 2em;
  background: darkgray;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch1-label {
  background: lightblue;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch1-label:before {
  content: "OPEN";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox+.onoffswitch1-label:before {
  content: "CLOSED";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5em;
  left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch1-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px white inset;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch1-label .onoffswitch1-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch1-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch1-label .onoffswitch1-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="onoffswitch1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch1" class="onoffswitch1-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch1" checked>
  <label class="onoffswitch1-label" for="myonoffswitch1">
    <span class="onoffswitch1-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch1-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, sir

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<div class="switchcontainer">
    <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn"><div class="slider round"><span class="on">ON</span><span class="off">OFF</span></div></label>
    </div>




    .switchcontainer{
      margin-top:25px;
    }
    .switchcontainer .on{
      margin-top:-25px;
      color:green;
    }
    .switchcontainer .off{
      margin-top:-25px;
      color:red;
    }
    .switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 90px;
      height: 34px;
          border: 2px solid #999999;
        border-radius: 30px;
    }

    .switch input {display:none;}

    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
          background-color: #EEEEEE;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
      box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
    }

    .slider:before {   
        content: "";
        height: 30px;
        width: 26px;
        left: 0px;
        bottom: 4px;
        background-color: white;
        -webkit-transition: .4s;
        transition: .4s;
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        margin: 0px;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        border: 2px solid #999999;
        border-radius: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 56px;
        -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%);
        background-image: linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px white inset;
    }

    input:checked + .slider {
          background-color: #2FCCFF;
          box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
    }

    input:focus + .slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }

    input:checked + .slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
      transform: translateX(55px);
    }

    /*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/
    .on
    {
      display: none;
    }

    .on, .off
    {
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    input:checked+ .slider .on
    {display: block;}

    input:checked + .slider .off
    {display: none;}

    /*--------- END --------*/

    /* Rounded sliders */
    .slider.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }

    .slider.round:before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/8LqLczyh/1/

Answer (score 0):

I create a switch button for you check this out

this is the html

```
<div class="switch">
  <input class="toggle" id="toggle-1" type="checkbox" >
  <label class="c-label-switch" for="toggle-1"></label>
  <label class="c-label" for="toggle-1">Remember password </label>
</div>
```

and this is the css

```
.switch {
    display: block;
}

.switch span {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #141414;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.switch .c-label {
    padding: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.toggle {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -9999px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.toggle + label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.c-label-switch {
    border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
}

.toggle + label:before, .toggle + label:after {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 9px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
}

.toggle + label:before {
    content: "No";
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-indent: -93px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    line-height: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.toggle + label:after {
    content: "Yes";
    text-indent: 35px;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 1px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    margin-left: 1px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #141414;
}

.toggle:checked + label:before {
    background-color: #0065b3;
    text-indent: 0;
}

.toggle:checked + label:after {
    margin-left: 41px;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.toggle + label:before, .toggle + label:after {
    transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: sir its not my problem ,

Comment: You want to label yes and no be invisible?

Comment: you need to have empty content for before and after elements like this .onoffswitch1-inner:after { content:'' "}